# How to exit a conduit when using mergeSources

Tags: haskell

I have a simple forked conduit setup, with two inputs feeding one single output....

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.TMChan
import Data.Conduit.Network

main::IO ()
main = do
  runTCPClient (clientSettings 3000 "127.0.0.1") $ \server -> do
      runResourceT $ do

        input <- mergeSources [
          transPipe liftIO (appSource server),
          infiniteSource
          ] 2

        input $$ transPipe liftIO (appSink server)

infiniteSource::MonadIO m=>Source m B.ByteString
infiniteSource = do
  liftIO $ threadDelay 10000000
  yield "infinite source"
  infiniteSource
```

(here I connect to a tcp socket, then combine the socket input with a timed infinite source, then respond back to the socket)

This works great, until the connection is dropped....  Because the second input still exists, the conduit keeps running.  (In this case, the program does end when the timed input fires and there is no socket to write to, but this isn't always the case in my real example).

What is the proper way to shut down the full conduit when one of the inputs is closed?

I tried to brute force a crash by adding the following

```
crashOnEndOfStream::MonadIO m=>Conduit B.ByteString m B.ByteString
crashOnEndOfStream = do
awaitForever $ yield
error "the peer connection has disconnected" --tried with error
liftIO $ exitWith ExitSuccess --also tried with exitWith
```

but because the input conduit runs in a thread, the executable was immune to runtime exceptions shutting it down (plus, there is probably a smoother way to shut stuff down than halting the program).

Answer (score 1):

the `Source` created by `mergeSources` keeps a count of unclosed sources. It's only closed when the count reaches 0 i.e. every upstream source is closed. This mechanism and the underlying TBMChannel is hidden from user code so you have no way to change its behavior.

One possible solution is to create the channel and the source manually with some medium-level functions exported by [`Data.Conduit.TMChan`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-conduit-2.7.0/docs/Data-Conduit-TMChan.html#sinkTBMChan), so you can finalize the source by closing the TBMChannel.  I haven't tested the code below since your program is not runnable on my machine.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import           Control.Concurrent           (threadDelay)
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import qualified Data.ByteString              as B
import           Data.Conduit
import           Data.Conduit.Network
import           Data.Conduit.TMChan

main::IO ()
main = do
  runTCPClient (clientSettings 3000 "127.0.0.1") $ \server -> do
      runResourceT $ do
        -- create the TBMChannel
        chan <- liftIO $ newTBMChanIO 2
        let
          -- everything piped to the sink will appear at the source
          chanSink = sinkTBMChan chan True
          chanSource = sourceTBMChan chan
        tid1 <- resourceForkIO $ appSource server $$ chanSink
        tid2 <- resourceForkIO $ infiniteSource $$ chanSink

        chanSource $$ transPipe liftIO (appSink server)

        -- and call 'closeTBMChan chan' when you want to exit.
        -- 'chanSource' will be closed when the underlying TBMChannel is closed.

infiniteSource :: MonadIO m => Source m B.ByteString
infiniteSource = do
  liftIO $ threadDelay 10000000
  yield "infinite source"
  infiniteSource
```